# flutter:: How to call listview using obx?

Tags: flutter, dart

Record.dart

```
class Record extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String>? records;
  const Record({
    Key? key,
    required this.records,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RecordState createState() => _RecordState();
}

class _RecordState extends State<Record> {
   ....
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.records == null ? SizedBox() : ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.records!.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      reverse: true,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
        return Card(
          elevation: 5,
          child: ExpansionTile(
      ...
```

record_body.dart

```
class record_Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _record_Body createState() => _record_Body();
  static List<String>? records;
}
class _record_Body extends State<record_Body> {
   List<String>? get record => video_Body.records;
   ...
```

before

```
 Container(
      height: 300,
      child: IconButton(
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Record(
                  records: video_Body.records,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.mic, color: Colors.green, size: 45)
      ),
    ),
```

after

```
body: Obx(() {
          switch(RouteName.values[controller.currentIndex.value]) {

            case RouteName.Record:
               return Record(records: video_Body.records); // error
```

Originally 'Record'(in record.dart) was loaded via navigator.push.
I want to load the listview using obx instead of navigator.push.
In my after, the listview is not visible. How do I solve this?